# Declare class in .h file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Why this gives me an error in my .h file?
I have a `pageViewController` and in the `mainViewController` file I want to call the `contentViewController` just once and not for any modification.

```
contentViewController *content; //this gives me an error
```

Comment: We need to see the code to be able to help

Comment: I have to get a string that the user changes from the textView. This textView is declared and used in this contentViewController and I have to get the string from my mainViewController!

Comment: Where is the code ? What is the error ?

Comment: this is my firstViewController .h:

Comment: @GiovanniFilaferro, Did my below answer fixed your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .h file, above `@interface`, did you put `@class contentViewController;` That could be an issue here.